# NSArray out of Order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an NSArray of 6, CMTimes it looks like this:

```
 (
"CMTime: {0/600 = 0.000}",
"CMTime: {600/600 = 1.000}",
"CMTime: {1200/600 = 2.000}",
"CMTime: {1800/600 = 3.000}",
"CMTime: {2400/600 = 4.000}",
"CMTime: {3000/600 = 5.000}",
"CMTime: {3600/600 = 6.000}"
)
```

And then in a method I have

```
NSValue *myTime = [times objectAtIndex:i];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myTime, nil];
//Also all these get logged before anything inside block is logged, when I 
//looping the whole thing
NSLog(@"%@", array);
[imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:array completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error) {
//HERE its not in order

    NSString *requestedTimeString = (NSString *) CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, requestedTime));
    NSString *actualTimeString = (NSString *) CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, actualTime));
    NSLog(@"Requested: %@; actual %@", requestedTimeString, actualTimeString);
```

Where i is an NSInteger and is increased with a loop. And then in the next line I am passing this array of one value to `imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes` but, when I do this inside the `generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes` method, the times are out of order, even though one line before I logged them and they were in order?

What is going on here, and how can I fix it?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

Comment: This methods "generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes" seems like doing things asynchronously in multiple threads. So you cannot guarantee that they can be in order, unless you have code for this API, where you do task asynchronously on a serial queue.

Comment: @gagarwal okay, but I am passing the times in one at a time, so shouldn't it output in the order of input, or are you saying that its one at a time, but processing more than one at a time, and is just outputting in the order it finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are making separate one entry arrays and then passing them into the async method.  I believe the purpose of generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:handler method is to batch the operation (you are doing that job for it maybe?).  Now things can come back in any order (or maybe on separate threads complicating the issue).

Try to pass the whole array (times) at once.

Alternatively, the completion handler provides enough information for you to insert the images in sorted order to a different collection.

---

In response to your comments:

```
NSMutableArray *completedList = [NSMutableArray array];
__block count = [array count];
[imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:array completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error) {
    // Check the time here, insert the items to the array in order using something like
    [completedList insertObject: image atIndex: indexThatItShouldGoInOrder];
    // Or adding them all and sorting them at the end, whichever is easier
    count--;    // Wait till you have them all
    if(!count) {
        // Here trigger the other stuff you were going to do because it's done.
    }
}];
```

This might need to be a little more complicated if the handler is running on multiple threads.  You will need to use GCD to guard the array/sort/insert.  You will also need to make sure the count--, checking count is atomic.

Depending on what you're trying to do, doing a dispatch_async() in the if(!count) block might also make sense.

Comment: right, but I can't pass them all in at the same time because I am holding the execution of other code until, all this is done, and for that other part to be held I need to pass them one at a time

Comment: I'm not sure that's true even if you pass them in one at a time?  Ideally in the completion handler you can trigger any work that is dependent on one image completing?  What is the dependent work?

Comment: I am using bolts framework are you familiar with it?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  But if you outline the steps that the program needs to do I can try to help.

Comment: So basically I have these times and I am generating an image from an AVAsset, and then added the image generated to an array, and then once all images are in array I do other stuff

Comment: Edited the answer to something that will hopefully be useful.